# Javascript filter not working for multiple condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

I am trying to filter array of objects on the basis of some conditions. If I apply single condition it works but if I applied some more condition it doesn't worked!!. I don't understand why its not working for multiple conditions.Below is my code.

```js
const removeItemIfConditationMatch = () => {
  let filter = [];
  filter = arr.filter(
    item => item.id !== myObj.id && 
    item.level !== myObj.level && 
    item.technology !== myObj.technology && 
    item.type !== myObj.type)
  console.log(filter)
}

let myObj = {
  "questions": [],
  "technology": "Can_Js",
  "type": "NON_CODE",
  "level": "EASY",
  "id": 0
}
let arr = [{
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Can_Js",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "EASY",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Network_Simulator",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "EASY",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Java",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "HIGH",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Java",
    "type": "CODE",
    "level": "HIGH",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "React Js",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "MEDIUM",
    "id": 1
  }
]
removeItemIfConditationMatch()
```

In the above code if I filter on single condition it works but if you run above code it won't work. Anyone have any idea why Its not working where I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

After applying my multi filter criteria I am expecting below result.

```js
[
    {
        "questions": [],
        "technology": "Network_Simulator",
        "type": "NON_CODE",
        "level": "EASY",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "questions": [],
        "technology": "Java",
        "type": "NON_CODE",
        "level": "HIGH",
        "id": 0
    },
    {
        "questions": [],
        "technology": "Java",
        "type": "CODE",
        "level": "HIGH",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "questions": [],
        "technology": "React Js",
        "type": "NON_CODE",
        "level": "MEDIUM",
        "id": 1
    }
]
```

In short I am expecting if my condition match then remove that Object from array list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace the condition to:

```
filter = arr.filter(item => !(item.id == myObj.id &&
                    item.level == myObj.level && 
                    item.technology == myObj.technology && 
                    item.type == myObj.type))
```

In your code the original filter removes all objects where ANY field equals to the value in `myObj` object. In suggested code filter function removes objects where ALL fields are not equal to the fields in `myObj`.

The problem is here: if you want to remove value from an array with the condition:

```
   item.id !== myObj.id && item.level !== myObj.level ...
```

if `id` fields are not equal then JS stops to verify the condition and drops this element from the result array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const removeItemIfConditationMatch = () => {
  let filter = [];
  filter = arr.filter(
    item => item.id !== myObj.id || 
    item.level !== myObj.level || 
    item.technology !== myObj.technology || 
    item.type !== myObj.type)
  console.log(filter)
}

let myObj = {
  "questions": [],
  "technology": "Can_Js",
  "type": "NON_CODE",
  "level": "EASY",
  "id": 0
}
let arr = [{
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Can_Js",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "EASY",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Network_Simulator",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "EASY",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Java",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "HIGH",
    "id": 0
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "Java",
    "type": "CODE",
    "level": "HIGH",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "questions": [],
    "technology": "React Js",
    "type": "NON_CODE",
    "level": "MEDIUM",
    "id": 1
  }
]
removeItemIfConditationMatch()
```

Comment: You are using && but I think you mean to use || or. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Answer (score 1):

```js
const removeItemIfConditationMatch = () => {
  let filter = [];
  let myObj = {
    questions: [],
    technology: "Can_Js",
    type: "NON_CODE",
    level: "EASY",
    id: 0,
  };
  let arr = [
    {
      questions: [],
      technology: "Can_Js",
      type: "NON_CODE",
      level: "EASY",
      id: 0,
    },
    {
      questions: [],
      technology: "Network_Simulator",
      type: "NON_CODE",
      level: "EASY",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      questions: [],
      technology: "Java",
      type: "NON_CODE",
      level: "HIGH",
      id: 0,
    },
    {
      questions: [],
      technology: "Java",
      type: "CODE",
      level: "HIGH",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      questions: [],
      technology: "React Js",
      type: "NON_CODE",
      level: "MEDIUM",
      id: 1,
    },
  ];
  filter = arr.filter(
    (item) =>
      item.id !== myObj.id ||
      item.level !== myObj.level ||
      item.technology !== myObj.technology ||
      item.type !== myObj.type
  );
  console.log(filter);
};

removeItemIfConditationMatch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this filter instead

```
arr.filter((item) => JSON.stringify(item) !== JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

Remember that in your solution you specified multiple conditions, which usually have unexpected behavior in JavaScript. Logic is inverted, therefore you would have to use `||` instead of `&&`